# How query based on the datestamp which is a string data type in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

Here is the how the datastamp is in my json.I need to query based on the time stamp.

Datastamp:2016-02-10T11:43:15----string type

I tried querying by using substr which didn't work.

```
db.General_Liability.aggregate({$project : {new_time_stamp : {$substr : ["$session.Datestamp",0, 10]}}});
```

Please let me know how i should query.

Comment: I need to query only "2016-02-10".

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need a query for one day. You can use $gt and $lt for this.

```
db.General_Liability.find({ "session._Datestamp":{"$gte":ISODate("2016-02-10T00:00:00"), "$lt":ISODate("2016-02-11T00:00:00")}})
```